# How can I use a object reference stored in a variable as a string?

Tags: javascript, string, variables, object

If I have a variable foo that hold a reference to an object:

```
var foo = someObj;
```

How can I then use the name of the object as a string?

I tried:

```
var bar = foo.valueOf()
```

But that just returned another reference to the object.

What I have is an algorithm that selects from a large number of objects.  I then want to use the name of that object to select from amongst a group of HTML elements.  Using the following does not work either (returns null):

```
document.getElementById(foo)
```

Thank you.

Comment: `var foo = {bar};` isn't valid JavaScript.  Object literals need a key and a value.  Objects don't know the name of their variable (you can make a value in the object containing it, however).  You can get an object's keys or values, but not its name.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more? what do you mean by `var foo = {bar}`
and what you expect in var bar?

Comment: I was simply trying to show that foo held a reference to an object and not just another variable.  I'm fairly new.  I edited to make it more clear.

Comment: Do you want `var bar` to contain `'foo'`?

Comment: No.  When a variable hold a reference to an object, I want to be able to pass the object name to a function as a string.

Comment: So, if you had `var foo = someObj;`, you'd want `var bar` to contain `"someObj"`?  Pretty sure you can't do that.

Answer (score 4):

There is no reliable way to get the name of the object.

Example:

```
var obj = {};
var obj1 = obj;
var obj2 = obj;

magically_get_and_print_name(obj);  // What to print? "obj"? "obj1"? "obj2"?
```

Methods to get the name in some cases:

- Function declarations - [`funcreference.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Name) (non-standard, though well-supported)
- Constructor instances - `instance.constructor.name`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have:

```
var someObj = {
    a: 15,
    b: 36
};
```

And then you did:

```
var foo = someObj;
```

There's no way to get the string `"someObj"` (or `"foo"`) from `foo`.

What you could do, is add the name to the object when creating it.  Something like this:

```
var someObj = {
    a: 15,
    b: 36,
    objName: 'someObj'
};
var foo = someObj;
console.log(foo.objName); // "someObj"
```